# Blur text in iMovie 10.0.7

Tags: imovie

I want to blur sensitive information in my video. How do I do that in iMovie 10.0.7?

"Adjust", "Video Overlay settings" options are missing.

[image: If I select an image I don't get adjust & video overlay settings option]

Answer (score 1):

I found an [apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471468?tstart=0) that seemingly answers your question:

**Question**

> I went to the help menu and it instructs me to click an icon that doesn't appear.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Answer**

> Yes I had this problem as well, I found out that you have to Drag the clip from EVENTS into your PROJECT.
>
> But when you do so, make sure that you drag it just over the top, not actually into the clip. The icon should then appear.

I am sure that `Video Overlay settings` have the same reason to not show up as the `Adjust` option

Hope this helps